# file system watcher doesn't work when used full filename as filter

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm trying setup a file watcher for one specific file `C:\test.json` via [workspace.createFileSystemWatcher](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.createFileSystemWatcher)

This is the code I use:

```js
const watcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(new vscode.RelativePattern("C:\\", "test.json"));
watcher.onDidChange(uri => console.log("change", uri));
watcher.onDidCreate(uri => console.log("create", uri));
watcher.onDidDelete(uri => console.log("delete", uri));
```

For some reason events are not triggered, unless I replace filter `test.json` with `*.json` - then it works just fine.

Any ideas why complete filename doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your question(s) ;>} on github.  I'll post there as well.

It is interesting that this works:

```js
const watcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(new vscode.RelativePattern(vscode.Uri.file("C:\\Testing"), "test.json"));
```

Note that `test.json` is in a folder `Testing`.

This does not work - when `test.json` is at the root of `C`:

```js
const watcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(new vscode.RelativePattern(vscode.Uri.file("C:\\"), "test.json"));
```

So it looks like either `vscode.Uri.file("C:\\")` doesn't work properly at the drive root level or `vscode.RelativePattern()` doesn't work properly at the drive root level.

As we discussed on github (see [API: createFileSystemWatcher() doesn't work when filter set to a specific file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162498)), the problem appears to be the trailing slash in `C:\\`.  Since relative patterns like `new vscode.RelativePattern(vscode.Uri.file("C:\\Testing"), "test.json")` work and patterns like `new vscode.RelativePattern(vscode.Uri.file("C:\\Testing\\"), "test.json")` do not work.

But a backslash is required for a drive root level designation:

> No, it doesn't. But it's because drive path requires trailing slash,
> otherwise it's treated as relative path instead:
>
> Use a backslash as required as part of volume names, for example, the
> "C:" in "C:\path\file" or the "\server\share" in
> "\server\share\path\file" for Universal Naming Convention (UNC)
> names.

from your comment at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162498#issuecomment-1295628237

so it does seem that `vscode.RelativePattern()` will not work at the drive root level because of the trailing slash (but the trailing slash is necessary and a simple `vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(vscode.Uri.file("C:\\test.json"));` does not work either).

We should update this answer with however the github issue is resolved - can your original `new vscode.RelativePattern(vscode.Uri.file("C:\\"), "test.json")` be made to work.